# confusion between sencha touch 2 and Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference of Native packaging between Sencha touch2 and PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725591/difference-of-native-packaging-between-sencha-touch2-and-phonegap)

I've read many articles on the difference between Sencha Touch and Phonegap. [This one](http://beautyindesign.com/blog/titanium-phonegap-sencha-touch-jquery-mobile-clearing-up-confusion/) 
for instance. It confused me. Initially I thought Sencha Touch was just a framework to build "Mobile Web applications" and Phonegap was to build "Native Applications for Mobile phones" using JS, HTML5 and CSS3. 
When I visited the Sencha website and read about Sencha Touch "2". I learn that it comes with Native packaging, which allows user to use Native device API's through `Ext.device`

```
Ext.device.Camera.capture({}); //An example
```

In several forums i read that "Sencha Touch and Phonegap" go "hand in hand". for me it meant that Sencha Touch is used only to create the GUI of the application  and Phonegap is used for accessing Native device API's and creating Cross platform builds. But after reading the description of Sencha Touch 2 i got confused.
Can someone explain me what exactly these two frameworks are used for ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is possible duplicated.

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725591/difference-of-native-packaging-between-sencha-touch2-and-phonegap)

I think first answer can give you some basic idea about the difference between these two frameworks

Comment: you should add the doubt in comment

Comment: i read it, was useful, is it safe to say that sencha touch 2 is trying to get to where phonegap is? with introduction to native device api's?

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't see any reason why they don't want to follow this path because they said that Sencha touch will support more platforms beside iOS, Android, BlackBerry and Kindle Fire(Amazon tablet) in the future which I believe will result in Sencha SDK Tools expansion over iOS and Android as well